# Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'

Tags: android, gradle, build

I´m trying to add an dynamic module to my app, but i´m recieving the following error. It happens when i try to build it:

```
Execution failed for task ':admin:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Error while evaluating property 'applicationId' of task     ':admin:generateDebugBuildConfig'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':admin:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'applicationId'.
  > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
     > Collection is empty.'''
```

Im using:

```
Kotlin: 1.5.21
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha05")
```

Here is my build.gradle of the admin module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
android {
    compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "io.github.diegoflassa.admin"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing, that your dynamic feature module must depend on your main module. Most probably, something like the following in your dynamic features's build.gradle will help:

`implementation project(':app')`